# Specifying Node Id for use by views in attachment

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, attachment

I have created a photo album content type and a related photo content type. I can click on the photo album content and view all the referenced photo images with no problem. My goal now is to create a block that displays a slideshow of the photos referenced by the most recent album only. Photo content contains a required entity reference to the photo album.

I have created a block which pulls the most recent album only, and that works as expected, but I'm darned if I can figure out how to create the corresponding attachment slideshow view, I just can't figure out how to send the photo album node ID to the attachment. There are no arguments so I can't figure out how to pass one.

Any research suggestions would be more than welcome also. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "attachment", but this is how I would organize this.

To your album content type you can add node reference field referencing to photos. You can choose from various set of widgets (autocomplete, drop-down...).
And for number of referenced nodes set unlimited...or some other number you want.

Then, when you create a block you have your album node id. Load that node and inside node object you'll find the array of related photos. So you can iterate trough that array, load photo nodes one by one and print they field values you need.

**Added:**

And if you want more then one view on the page you can embed additional view(s) from main view template file:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Or, you can use:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

and collect results, loop trough them.

You can easily pass parameters to both functions. Not sure why it's not mentioned in those function description, but check in the comments - they accept more than 2 parameters!

And I never used those attachments, sorry.

Comment: Thank you Milan! I have one node for the photo album (content type: album) and I have multiple nodes, one each for the photos (content type: photo). The photos each have the album referenced, via entity reference. I have a view which shows the most recent album but the view has no arguments, the view does show the album Node ID, I just can't figure out how to pass that ID to a view attachment (please see http://nmc-codes.blogspot.com/2012/10/views-attachment-in-drupal-7.html for an example of what I mean by attachment)

Comment: Added my comment to my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks again Milan, I will investigate both those possibilities. I really do appreciate your research and time!

Comment: Yep Milan, I got it working! I used the views_embed_view and called my 'attachment' display with it. Thanks Again, Paul

Comment: One more trick - if you select "embed" display type (may be disabled by default - check view settings) when you embed it you'll get common admin edit links. You know, when you hover it and you are logged in as admin edit link appear at top right corner.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Milan. That is another module (admittedly a very small module) and I really would like to avoid any more overhead! If I needed exposed filters it would be needed so I have it added to my little list of things I might one day need!